# VBA replace certain carriage

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, return, paragraph

All.

I am used to programming VBA in Excel, but am new to the structures in Word.
I am working through a library of text files to update them.   Many of them are either OCR documents, or were manually entered.

Each has a recurring pattern, the most common of which is unnecessary carriage returns.

For example, I am looking at several text files where there is a double return after each line.  A search and replace of all double carriage returns removes all paragraph distinctions.
However, each line is approximately 30 characters long, and if I manually perform the following logic, it gives me a functional document.

If there is a double carriage return after 30+ characters, I replace them with a space.
If there were less than 30 characters prior to the double return, I replace them with a single return.

Can anyone help me with some rudimentary code that would help me get started on that?  I could then modify it for each "pattern" of text documents I have.

e.g.

```
In this case, there are more than

thirty characters per line.  And I

will keep going to illustrate this

example.

This would be a new paragraph, and

would be separated by another of

the single returns.
```

I want code that would return:

`In this case, there are more than thirty character returns.  And I will keep going to illustrate this example.`

`This would be a new paragraph, and would be separated by another of the single returns.`

Let me know if anyone can throw something out that I can play with!

Comment: I tried to adjust your example since the site's formatting removes extra spaces. Not sure if I got it right...  I just went through something similar with a set of huge files... and finally figured out RegEx in the process.  That's likely the easiest/fastest way...  Have you used RegEx?   Also, is this a one-time thing or something that needs automation for the future? If one-time for a set of files (or rare enough that it can be done manually), I can answer with steps using Notepad++. Otherwise, VBA+RegEx could be better. And just to confirm, you said these are *text** files? (not `docx` etc)

Comment: +1 for the RegEx and NP++ idea... you can use RegEx in VBA but it takes a bit of setting up... you might want to mess around here: https://regex101.com/r/zG9GPw/1

Comment: Great, thanks, I will!

Comment: @ashleedawg - I've just started playing a bit   I have not used RegEx, but it does look useful.   It's essentially a one-time shot, so if you've got steps using Notepad++, that would be great.   Yes - these are text files, not docx or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without code (which RegEx requires), simply using Word's own *wildcard* Find/Replace tools, where:

```
Find = ([!^13]{30,})[^13]{1,}
Replace = \1^32
```

and, to clean up the residual multi-paragraph breaks:

```
Find = [^13]{2,}
Replace = ^p
```

You could, of course, record the above as a macro...

Comment: Thanks!   I hadn't played around with the conditional statements in Find/Replace.   I will play with the coding answers as well, just to wrap my head around the options.

Comment: Thanks!   Still not getting exactly the results I want, but I've just started looking at the Find/Replace wildcards.

Comment: You might find http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/29880-cleaning-up-text-pasted-websites-e-mails.html helpful for dealing with clean-up issues more generally. For some useful info on wildcards see https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again, still playing with it.  I think the issue is that some of the carriage returns are not the same character...  It replaces some of the double returns as I expect, but seems to miss some of them.   Anyway, will keep playing, just wanted to say thanks for this option in addition to the coding ones!

Comment: The second F/R will replace all repeated carriage returns with a single one, though you may end up with a pair of them before a table if your document has any. Perhaps your document also has manual line breaks. With Word's formatting display on, you'll see paragraph breaks as ¶ symbols and manual line breaks as ↵ symbols. And, if you're working with tables, their end-of-cell & end-of-row markers look like the ¤ symbol; you can't delete those via Find/Replace.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a RegEx that might work for you:

`(\n\n)(?<!\.(\n\n))`

The substitution is just a plain space, you can try it out (and modify / tweak it) here: https://regex101.com/r/zG9GPw/4

This 'pattern' tells the RegEx engine to look for the newline character `\n` which occurs x2 like this `\n\n` *(worth noting this is from your question and might be different in your files, e.g. could be \r\n)* and it *assumes* that a valid line break will be proceeded by a full stop: `\.`.

In RegEx the full stop symbol is a single character wild card so it needs to be escaped with the '\' (*n* and *r* are normal characters, escaping them tells the RegEx engine they represent newline and return characters).

So... the expression is looking for a group of x2 newline characters but then uses a negative look-behind to exclude any matches where the previous character was a full stop.

Anyway, it's all explained on the site:
[image]

---

Here is how you could do a RegEx find and replace using NotePad++ (I'm not sure if it comes with RegEx or if a plugin is needed, either way it is easy). But you can set a location, filters (to target specific file types), and other options (such as search in sub-directories).

[image]

Other than that, as @MacroPod pointed out you could also do this with MS Word, document by document, not using any code :)

Comment: Thanks - just starting playing with RegEx and coding, and having fun with it - lol - but need to get these done before I have fun.   Will try a few of the other options, then will teach myself a bit more about that!  :)

Comment: @BLP_1975 hey, for a single shot NotePad++ will do this easily (assuming you are using plain text files). I'll update my answer with an image for NP++